# How to convert a public RSA key to JSON Web Key

Tags: go, cryptography, rsa, jwk

I have a RSA public key like this in pem format and I want to convert it into the JSON Web Key.

RSA:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

 MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUBB4GNADCBiQKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0
 FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUpwmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/
 3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ51s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQAB

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

JWK:

```
{"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","kid":"201","use":"sig","alg":"RS256","n":"gslsSwlsweQKOG5sHLJEZ8-
_cWBTiMhuEc59ETC1raGKRmjYcp2UQulzyHC5it30JEfITQGScDeRefNw9pdsG2CEM0wBqji8ib_HEbVm1JjQZNqHxv4
2I6LeK2O2qaDcePcM9DlpAuprnJndhElk0NuRO_Q6vl8WQT7g1TlSxLWxcUgyuK8YmYNThgSkX9Y47oCDX3bFkH60YG6c4IcWHJPRKb
X5rgnTe8hGflfR3k","e":"AQAB"}]}
```

I couldn't found a way to successfully do it in Go.

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/jwk

Comment: @Vorsprung I couldn't found a way to use pem format in this package

Answer (score 1):

here it is:

```
   pubKey, err := ioutil.ReadFile("pathToPublicKey")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("key not found", err)
        return err
    }

    pubPem, _ := pem.Decode(pubKey)

    pub, _ := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(pubPem.Bytes)

    set, err := jwk.New(pub)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to convert to JWK: %s", err)
        return err
    }

    err = jwk.AssignKeyID(set)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to assign kid: %s", err)
        return err
    }
```

I used this package:
godoc.org/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/jwk

Comment: Thanks Javad, I will check it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Solution that uses other popular libraries. Load `publicKey` bytes however you want e.g. from a file, Vault etc… Use `json.Marshal` on `jose.JSONWebKeySet` to get the JSON response.

```
package auth

import (
    "github.com/go-jose/go-jose/v3"
    "github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4"
)

type JwkProvider interface {
    Provide() (*jose.JSONWebKeySet, error)
}

type rsaJwkProvider struct {
    keyID     string
    publicKey []byte
}

func NewRsaJwkProvider(keyID string, publicKey []byte) JwkProvider {
    return &rsaJwkProvider{keyID: keyID, publicKey: publicKey}
}

func (p *rsaJwkProvider) Provide() (*jose.JSONWebKeySet, error) {
    rsaPublicKey, err := jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM(p.publicKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    jsonWebKey := jose.JSONWebKey{
        Key:       rsaPublicKey,
        KeyID:     p.keyID,
        Algorithm: "RS256",
        Use:       "sig",
    }
    return &jose.JSONWebKeySet{Keys: []jose.JSONWebKey{jsonWebKey}}, nil
}
```